# iOS in app consumable: purchase gets lost when credit card info is missing

Tags: ios, swift3, in-app-purchase

My iOS app has an in app purchase where user can buy consumables. Everything works as expected with one exception: when the user has missing credit card information during the purchase she gets redirected into the App Store while the app gets the transaction failed notification. When the user enters the missing information, a system dialog tells the user that the purchase was successful - but in the app I do not know anything about that. How can I get the information that the user purchased? In my app the user often does not return immediately into the app and so she paid but does not get the service...

Comment: There is an AppStore api to see purchase all relevant purchases.. Maybe you can use this when coming back to app after purchase has been started?

Comment: Are you getting "transaction failed" or "transaction deferred"? If failed, what error message / code are you getting?

Comment: How does this api look like? And isn’t there a way to be notified in the background (app is still running in the background, not closed completely)

Comment: @swalkner you use StoreKit. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in_app_purchase especially **SKReceiptRefreshRequest**

Comment: This is the full guide https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267

Answer (score 0):

When you come back to the app you just use this:

```
let request = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()
request.delegate = self
request.start()
```

This will give you all purchases that made for your app from this user ;)

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267)

Comment: but how to handle this if the user does not return into the app?

Comment: is it impossible in the background?

Comment: Why do you care if it's in background or not? The user needs this when he enters the app. Not before.. It's not possible in background

Comment: no, a service is started when the user did an in app purchase, i.e. an API call is triggered which is important that it happens immediately.

Comment: maybe you can make a different api call when user starts the process, and make a silent push notification 1 hour later that will wake up the app. Or second option is to ask the user activate purchase in the app after payment completed. And that activation button will trigger the api call if it didn't occur already